# QTablewidget doesn't show new cellWidgets in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

My Program is written in Python3.5 and PyQt5. I have a method in my class that adds some custom widgets to a QTableWidget. when I call the function from inside the class it works and changes the cellwidgets of QTablewidget but when I call it from another custom class it doesn't change the widgets. I checked and the items and indexes changes but the new cellwidgets doesn't show. what is the problem?
This is my code:

```
class mainmenupage(QWidget):
    elist = []
    def __init__(self):
        #the main window widget features
        self.setObjectName("mainpage")
        self.resize(800, 480)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(800, 480))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(800, 480))

        #the QTreeWidget features
        self.category_tree = QTreeWidget(self)
        self.category_tree.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.category_tree.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.category_tree.setGeometry(QRect(630, 90, 161, 381))
        self.category_tree.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.category_tree.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale.Persian, QLocale.Iran))
        self.category_tree.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.category_tree.setUniformRowHeights(False)
        self.category_tree.setColumnCount(1)
        self.category_tree.setObjectName("category_tree")
        self.category_tree.headerItem().setText(0, "1")
        self.category_tree.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.category_tree.header().setVisible(False)
        self.category_tree.header().setSortIndicatorShown(False)
        self.category_tree.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus))

        #the QTableWidget features. It comes from the custom class myTableWidget
        self.main_table = myTableWidget(self)
        self.main_table.setGeometry(QRect(20, 140, 600, 330))
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.main_table.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.main_table.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.main_table.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 0))
        self.main_table.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.main_table.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale.Persian, QLocale.Iran))
        self.main_table.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.main_table.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.main_table.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.main_table.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.main_table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.main_table.setTabKeyNavigation(False)
        self.main_table.setShowGrid(False)
        self.main_table.setCornerButtonEnabled(False)
        self.main_table.setUpdatesEnabled(True)

        self.main_table.setRowCount(2)
        self.main_table.setColumnCount(2)

        self.main_table.setObjectName("main_table")
        self.main_table.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.main_table.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
        self.main_table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.main_table.verticalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
        self.main_table.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.main_table.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)


        self.main_table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(300)
        self.main_table.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(165)

        self.category_tree.itemPressed.connect(self.insertdata)

    def insertdata(self,subcat):
        #get the text of clicked item from qtreewidget
        item = self.category_tree.currentItem().text(0)
        #get data from DB
        datas = self.conn.retrievedata('*','words',"subcat='{}'".format(item))
        #check if the list of copied data is empty or not
        if mainmenupage.elist != []:
            del mainmenupage.elist[:]
        #if the list is empty, the data received from DB appends to it
        if mainmenupage.elist == []:
            for data in datas:
                mainmenupage.elist.append(data)
            #delete the first index of copied list because it isn't needed here
            mainmenupage.elist = mainmenupage.elist[1:]
        # calls the populatemain function for populating qtablewidget with these datas with a custom index e.g. index 5 to 9.
        self.populatemain(5,9)

    def populatemain(self,startindexdata,endindexdata):
        #make a list for indexes of items that will be added to qtablewidget
        mtl=[]
        for i in range(2):
            for j in range(2):
                mtl.append(i)
                mtl.append(j)
        #adding custom widgets as cellWidgets to qtablewidget
        for index, my in enumerate(zip(*[iter(mtl)]*2)):
            if mainmenupage.elist != []:
                data = mainmenupage.elist[startindexdata:endindexdata][index]

                exec("self.iteM{} = CustomWidget('{}','content/img/food.png')".format(data[0],data[4]))
                exec("self.main_table.setCellWidget({} ,{}, self.iteM{})".format(*my,data[0]))


class myTableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def checking(self):
        if (self.endgingposx - self.startingposx) <= -50:
        #a custom function for checking that if the user made a swipe to left on the qtablewidget for chaning it's content
            if mainmenupage.elist != []:
                #make an instance from the previous class for accessing to populatemain method
                x = mainmenupage()
                #calling populatemain method for changing widgets in qtablewidget with the items made from different indexes of the copied data list e.g. indexes 0 to 4. but i don't know why this doesn't change the items. The populatemain function runs correctly it can be checked by putting print statement in it but it doesn't change the Qtablewidget contents.
                x.populatemain(0,4)
    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        self.startingposx = event.x()
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.endgingposx = event.x()
        self.checking()

class CustomWidget(QWidget):
     def __init__(self, text, img, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self._text = text
        self._img = img

        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.lbPixmap = QLabel(self)
        self.lbText = QLabel(self)
        self.lbText.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.lbPixmap)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.lbText)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
         self.lbPixmap.setPixmap(QPixmap(self._img).scaled(260,135,Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio,transformMode = Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        self.lbText.setText(self._text)


    @pyqtProperty(str)
    def img(self):
        return self._img

    @img.setter
    def total(self, value):
        if self._img == value:
            return
        self._img = value
        self.initUi()

    @pyqtProperty(str)
    def text(self):
        return self._text

    @text.setter
    def text(self, value):
        if self._text == value:
            return
        self._text = value
        self.initUi()
```

`self.category_tree` is a QTreeWidget

`self.main_table` is a QTableWidget

For completing my question. When I click on one of the `self.category_tree items` it calls `insertdata`. At the last line of `insertdata` I call `self.populatemain(5,9)` it adds 4 custom widgets to my table, but when the `checking` method from `myTableWidget` class calls `populatemain` with other indexes the qtablewidget items doesn't change. What's wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code is difficult to debug, but a common beginner error is that you do not set the number of columns and rows, ie if you want to insert the widget in the position i, j, this position must exist, so the number of rows and columns must be greater aiyj, in your case use the following code `self.main_table.setRowCount(2)  self.main_table.setColumnCount(2)` before adding the widgets.

Comment: Yes you are right I have this code. In the part `#some codes`  I already wrote this two lines. And because of that if you see i said the items come to table when i click on the category items and the populate main function happens both times. But I don't know why the time that the function is being called by that checking function doesn't shows new items. @eyllanesc

Comment: I can not give you any more suggestions if you do not show me a code that can test, since the current one can not execute it, if its code is extensive it can be shared by Dropbox, drive, etc.

Comment: @eyllanesc I updated the code. I think you can now use it for debugging.

Comment: I get an empty widget.

Comment: @eyllanesc https://pastebin.com/mgbJw27X This will work. And this is the image file https://ibb.co/ddmagv.

Comment: @eyllanesc nothing happened? :(

Comment: Your code is difficult to testing even if you have your code, if you explain what it is that you want your table to do you could help by typing the code.

Comment: @eyllanesc I want my table to change it's contents when the user swipe on it's area. Like swiping a gallery of photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of efforts finally I solved my problem this way:
I made a Qframe and putted the QTableWidget in it, and then I editted the mousePressEvent of the QTableWidget to call mousePressEvent of the QFrame that is below if this table, and then simply checked for starting and ending positions of clicking and made a function to update the QTableWidget's contents when swiping happens. I posted this to help anyone else that goes to problems like this.